# Глюк с выводом ошибки socket_strerror()

Tags: php

Пишу так

`echo "Ошибка: ".socket_strerror(socket_last_error());`

А выводит вот что `Ошибка: ����������� �� �����������, �.�. �������� ��������� ������ ������ �� �����������.`

Код ошибки показывает корректно отдельно и его номер я тоже знаю, вся проблема в том что не понятно с каких таких приколов выбивает вопросы? Кириллица как видите корректно отображается, что не так? Кстати UTF-8 без BOM

Comment: Так может у вас там Win 1251, а не UTF-8?

Comment: Латиница тоже корректно идет!

Comment: Кириллица разная бывает. Где Вы всё это наблюдаете? В линухе, в виндовзе, в консоли или в браузере?

Comment: @MaximPro, латиница в любой кодировке отображается корректно, на то она и латиница. `Кибернетика – буржуазная лженаука` такое мнение было в СССР, так что не кирилица заняла кодовые места с 0 до 127.

Comment: Windows, браузер Google Chrome

Comment: php где выполняется? там какая кодовая страница установлена? поди линух с koi8-r или windows с win1251? программу составляете в одной кодировке, а запускаете в среде с совершенно другой?

Comment: @Sergey простите за слова, но вы что отбитый? Зачем мне программу собирать в одной кодировке а запускать в другой? Я уже сказал Windows, а не линукс! Запускаю все через сборку xampp, проблем никогда не было, данная проблема связана именно с функцией `socket_strerror()`

Comment: Прежде чем кидаться обидными словами, почитали бы лучше инструкцию к функции socket_strerror(), в которой прямо упоминается зависимость результата от lc_messages. Либо текст программы набран в кодировке отличной от кодировки, диктуемой локалью "времени выполнения", либо функция не доделана для поддержки нужной локали. Плюс в виндовсе нет никаких родных lc_*, как именно на виндовсе php разбирается с локалью я лично не знаю, но очевидно что-то пытается делать (иначе думаю получили бы текст ошибки на аглицком)

Comment: Прежде чем писать подумали бы как реально помочь, а не писать сообщения для ламеров!(Вы своим сообщением тоже меня обидели так же как и я вас, но не открыто) Да я читал, я в курсе про lc_messages. Я пытался прописать для lc_messages что анлийский что русский выводд но ничего не помогло. Пока остается смотреть что за номер ошибки и если надо выводить варианты ошибок через  switch case

Answer (score 1):

```
iconv('WINDOWS-1251', 'UTF-8',socket_strerror($code_error));
```

Или

```
  $error=socket_strerror($value);
  $charset=mb_detect_encoding($error,'IBM866,WINDOWS-1251'); // для возможных кодировок см http://php.net/manual/ru/mbstring.supported-encodings.php
  $error=iconv($charset, 'UTF-8',$error);
```